# How to take string format and turn it into a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a format of a string like this:

{'ind': 'a', 'system': 'x'}

and I would like to turn it into a dictionary, how do I do so?

Comment: where are you getting this string from?

Comment: Is the string in valid JSON format?

Comment: the string does not seem to be in valid json format, this is a task I was given in my university

Comment: I have tried json.loads(str) but it does not work

Comment: This is the string representation of a python object. This is NOT JSON.

Comment: Something like [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) should work.

Answer (score 0):

Turning that string into JSON is easy enough, with `.replace()`.

```
import json, pprint

s = "{'ind': 'a', 'system': 'x'}"
d = json.loads(s.replace("'", '"'))
assert isinstance(d, dict)
pprint.pp(d, width=1)
```

produces

```
{'ind': 'a',
 'system': 'x'}
```

For more general cases, you may wish to rely on [ast.parse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.parse)
or [literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).